# Why Won't My Image Rotate in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I'm trying to do a simple animation that will rotate an image continuously when a button is clicked, but for some reason when I click the button it crashes the app.

Here's my code.

.h file:

```
@interface MainView : UIView {


}

IBOutlet UIImageView *sunray;

- (IBAction)pushrotate:(id)sender;



@end
```

.m file:

```
@implementation MainView


- (IBAction)pushrotate:(id)sender {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
    sunray.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(6.2831855);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void) dealloc {

    [sunray dealloc];
    [sunray release];
    [super dealloc];

}
@end
```

Any idea how I can make it work?  Also, what is the best way to make the animation start as soon as the app loads?

Comment: Have you checked if sunray is not nil ? Have you connected it properly in IB?

Comment: If it crashes then you've probably got your button wired up incorrectly. Please supply the message on the console following the crash.

Comment: Yeah the error code is terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException' and I did touch up inside for the button press.

Comment: Never send the dealloc message directly. [sunray release] ought to be enough for anybody.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your view rotation angle a multiply of 2*PI (it looks so in your case), then the view recognises that transformation does not actually have an effect and view is not rotated.

To rotate your view by angle more then 2*PI with animation you need to use CoreAnimation. So your code should look smth like:

```
//link with QuartzCore.framework
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>    
...
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
animation.duration = 1.0f;
[sanray.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"MyAnimation"];
```

Comment: In my console I get the error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: what exactly exception do you get?

Comment: I misspelled method name to create animation - it should be animationWithKeyPath, not animationForKeyPath - may be that was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You probably wired the action or the outlet up wrong (if you posted more console output, we would be sure). See if Interface Builder has any error markers on your actions/outlets.

Also see my comment about calling dealloc yourself - you shouldn't, except for [super dealloc] in your own dealloc implementation.

Comment: Steven - I had cocked up the action and outlets but have now fixed it and clicking the button does nothing now!

Comment: You're rotating by 2*PI -> full circle

Comment: Try rotating by M_PI_2 (which is a predefined constant, equivalent to 90 degrees) instead of 6.2831855

Comment: This works the first time I click rotate but not after.  Is there a predefined constant that will cause the image to rotate continuously?  (Until I click a stop button)

Comment: The transforms don't "Add up". Each time you set the transform, you overwrite what was there before. Simply increase the angle each time the button is tapped (you'll need to create a property for this, of course). Keep on adding 90 degrees (or rather, M_PI_2) on each tap, going over 360 degrees is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution to rotate a image

```
    -(void)rotate:(int)degree {
       float rad = M_PI * (float)degree / 180.0;

       [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
       [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
       aktivImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad);

       [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

i think you can also use this code snip with a button

in your IBAction you can code [self rotate:90]; to rate in 90°
or you can use [self rotate:0]; to not rotate your image ;-)